# Загрузка нескольких настроек логгера

Tags: java, intellij-idea, логирование, log4j

В программе есть несколько слабо пересекающихся модулей. Хотелось для каждого модуля сделать свой конфигурационный файл логгера.

Можно ли в стандартный `java.util.logging.Logger` загрузить настройки из нескольких конфигурационных файлов?

Когда делаю так

```
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(stream);
```

то запоминается только последний загруженный стрим. Более того затираются настройки для уже созданных логгеров.

Если ответ отрицательный, то тот же вопрос для `log4j` (с этим товарищем не работал вообще)

И третий вопрос. А не может ли IntellijIdea при сборке maven-проекта просто слить несколько файлов в один? Такой вариант тоже подойдет